# ContentFlow Javascript - Success Using Content Other Than Images?

Tags: javascript, image, slider, coverflow

I'd like to use the ContentFlow Javascript tool to display TEXT and other types of HTML rather than images. The documentation says [it's possible](http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/docu.php) but I have yet to discover how it works. Check out [my test page](http://niceguysatwork.com/wp-content/themes/suzane_northrop/testimonialflow/test.html) which just doesn't load when the content is something other than images. Code from this page follows. Any thoughts?

```
<Html>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="contentflow.js"></script>


    <div class="ContentFlow">
        <div class="loadIndicator"><div class="indicator"></div></div>
        <div class="flow">
            <div class="item" src="" title="">test content</div>
            <img class="item" src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/plugins/thickbox/images/plant4.jpg" title="Your_Image_Title"/>
    <img class="item" src="http://www.wired.com/images/article/magazine/1705/st_alphageek_f.jpg" title="Your_Image_Title"/>
            <img class="item" src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/plugins/thickbox/images/plant4.jpg" title="Your_Image_Title"/>
    <img class="item" src="http://www.wired.com/images/article/magazine/1705/st_alphageek_f.jpg" title="Your_Image_Title"/>
            <img class="item" src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/plugins/thickbox/images/plant4.jpg" title="Your_Image_Title"/>
        </div>
        <div class="globalCaption"></div>
        <div class="scrollbar"><div class="slider"><div class="position"></div></div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  What you have to do is put an inner div inside the ".item" div like this:

```
<div class="item"><div class="content">Text content to display</div></div>
```

As a caution, the docs say that the ".item" container itself will be scaled to be a particular size, but the text will NOT be scaled...sometimes leads to funny-looking stuff if you don't watch it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be as simple as the following:

```
<div class="ContentFlow">
    <div class="loadIndicator"><div class="indicator"></div></div>
    <div class="flow">
        <div class="item">test content</div>
        <div class="item">test content2</div>
        <div class="item">test content3</div>
        <div class="item">test content4</div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
              <span>this is also test content</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="globalCaption"></div>
    <div class="scrollbar"><div class="slider"><div class="position"></div></div></div>
</div>
```